# I am not able to send an audio or video file in chat software (such as WhatsApp, etc.)

Tags: networking, tcpip

My question is about data transfer on the Internet...

What is the difference between split packets by open-source software and TCP/IP structure on the internet for split(MTU fragmentation and sequence number packets)?

Why am I not able to send it, but I can with separation and smaller than the actual volume?

Is there a problem with the size?

Can I say the data transfer speed is the main reason?

Are the mechanism and performance based on the service provider's policies?

I am not able to send an audio or video file in chat software (such as WhatsApp, etc.).

When I send a video or audio file that size is 3 MB, no sending is done or 30% of the sending is done and it stops.

To find the problem, I used video or audio split software.
(https://github.com/c0decracker/video-splitter).

I the video that was not sent, I sent it with a video or audio splitter.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tool. Chat software generally uses [User Datagram Protocol (UDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol), which is meant for *immediate* transfer, not to handle large files. From Wikipedia, "UDP is suitable for purposes where error checking and correction are... not necessary. Time-sensitive applications often use UDP **because dropping packets is preferable to waiting for packets delayed due to retransmission**.

You can [create a chat application in Python](https://developer-shubham-rasal.medium.com/create-simple-chat-app-using-udp-protocol-in-python-4539cdbb1ae1), and see that, "It is a connectionless protocol and not reliable."

Use a method that has error checking and correction to send data, such as  [Transmission Control Protocol (TCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), used by FTP or [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol), or applications such as cloud storage software using HTTP.

Actually, I find it very impressive that even a few megabytes of data was transferred successfully without error control and correction!

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
My question is send a video or audio on the WhatsApp application,
I don't want to create a chat application.
I can't send on the Internet with the WhatsApp application, but I can send messages or pictures through the WhatsApp application.
Why can not?
but I send it after the split the video and audio through the WhatsApp application!!!
Why???

Comment: @hamizahedi, again, WhatsApp is not meant for data files.

Comment: Countries that use filtering to control the Internet
They have such problems.
We cannot send anything through chat programs.
Even with VPNs.

Comment: I am studying the infrastructure and performance of the internet platform
And I see that it is easy for governments to control and manage a service even based on encryption.
I had a question
Why should it be easy to jam and slow down and limit access to resources (while many services use the HTTPS service)?